# Mule SOAP to SOAP integration scenario

Tags: mule

Is there any way, compatible with computer science rules, to make at list 2 flows in one project  like this:

External system 1 -> SOAP endpoint (mule) ->  java object -> transformation ->  java object -> SOAP endpoint (mule) -> External system 2.

Our non working solution:
[single flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE7B7.png)

We experience bug [www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-5926]. Yes I read [stackoverflow.com/questions/25744541/mule-issue-more-than-one-jaxbcontext].

The solution which has nothing in common with the ESB philosophy but has one major single advantage, it works: looks like looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPxYe.png)

Some helpful resources:
[www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/] - notice please there are separate router and translator components.

Any ideas?

Best Regards, Apologies I can post only 2 links due to my reputation rank.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the last image works is more about what you cannot see. Just visually seeing the Java component on the MuleSoft canvas (screen where you "draw" the flow or integration solution) doesn't provide enough detail as to what the Java component is doing. And, while the icons on the canvas are nice, we generally inspect problems by looking at the XML.

Your question is not clear. The flow that you described in your image can't be discerned into an integration pattern I recognize and the details behind your flow design are vague.

Please provide your Mule config (XML) for the same flow, but first try to edit your question to explain exactly what you are trying to do. Stackoverflow is a place where problems are identified and problems are resolved. It's also a place for the history of what we do. It is up to us to do our homework before we add new questions. Myself or maybe someone else will help you but only after you clearly explain your problem. Yes, other solutions work but there's no way I can compare your flow to the simple one with the Java component without a LOT of background information.